# Icon and Screenshots in Google Play Store don't Update

Tags: android, google-play, icons

I had an app released on Google Play Store. I recently decided to change the icon and update the screenshots.

I changed the icon by going through the below steps:

1- Login to `Google Developers Console`.

2- From the dashboard selected: `"Store presence" -> "Store listing"`.

3- Upload a new icon.

4- Clicked on `"Submit Update"`.

Even though a couple of hours has passed from changing the icon, but I still see the old icon of Google Play Store.

Is there another step that I should be taking?

Answer (score 6):

Side menu, 4th item "publishing overview" seemed to do the job

Comment: I cannot see that item, I think is a matter of time

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

if you didn't receive any error during the upload of the images, or during the submit of the update, the update is pending, and should be visible in a couple of hours, sometimes it can take up to a day.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I just had to wait a couple more hours :D

Comment: Actually I figured out that I had 2 languages set for the store listing of my app: German and English. The reason that I didn't see my updates was that I was checking the English version of Google Play Store, despite the fact that the changes were only on the German language.

Comment: I have updated my screenshots two days ago and nothing has changed

Comment: @genericUser hi, I have the same problem for3 days now!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the left sidemenu go to **publishing overview** if you have any unpublished changes, they should be listen under the "Changes ready to publish" section.

If there are changes, click the **publish changes** button on the right corner of the section. It might take a couple of hours before the changes are visible.